# error LNK1104 : the path shown in the error message is not defined in additional dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, dependencies

I am getting an error LNK1104 in Visual Studio :

> LNK1104    cannot open file './x64/Release/zlib.lib'

when compiling my project.

The point is that I cannot see a corresponding path defined in **Additional Dependencies** of the linker in the project properties.

The error is shown when I add to the list of dependencies the right path to the **zlib.lib** or when I remove it.

here are the project compilation cmd line and linker :

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AnalysePMDSurf\PMDFilter\temp\Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /Fa"C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AnalysePMDSurf\PMDFilter\temp\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AnalysePMDSurf\PMDFilter\temp\Release\" /Fp"C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AnalysePMDSurf\PMDFilter\temp\Release\PMDFilter.pch"
```

and

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AnalysePMDSurf\PMDFilter\bin\Release\PMDFilter.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AnalysePMDSurf\PMDFilter\bin\Release\PMDFilter.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AnalysePMDSurf\opennurbs_20130711\bin\Release\opennurbs.lib" "C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AnalysePMDSurf\opennurbs_20130711\zlib\bin\Release\zlib.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AnalysePMDSurf\PMDFilter\bin\Release\PMDFilter.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AnalysePMDSurf\PMDFilter\temp\Release\PMDFilter.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I could solve it that way : create a new solution and new projects, copy-paste all the code files. Set the linking for the new projects and everything's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but have you tried two "\" instead one "\"?

Also, some of those errors might be [Linker Tools Error LNK1104](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s.aspx):

- Not enough disk space.
- File does not exist.
- When specifying libraries in a project's property pages dialog box,
  library names should be separated by spaces (and not commas).
- Incorrect filename or path.
- Invalid drive specification.
- Insufficient file permissions.
- Path for filename expands to more than 260 characters.
- If the given file is named LNKn, which is a filename generated by the
  linker for a temporary file, the directory specified in the TMP
  environment variable may not exist, or more than one directory is
  specified for the TMP environment variable. Only one directory path
  should be specified for the TMP environment variable.
- If the error message occurs for a library name, and you recently
  ported the .mak file from a previous Microsoft Visual C++ development
  system, the library may no longer be valid. Ensure that the library
  still exists in this circumstance.
- Another program may have the file open and the linker cannot write to
  it.
- Incorrect LIB environment variable. For information on how to update 
  the LIB environment variable, see VC++ Directories Property Page .
  Make sure any directories with libraries you need are listed here.

Comment: you mean in the paths in the linker ?

Comment: The `"\\"` is just for strings in program code, not for paths at the OS level.

Comment: This should have been a comment

Comment: @bradbury9 sorry, would love to add comment, but I must have at least **50 reputation** to comment other people posts.

Comment: Site privileges (such as commenting everywhere) are behind a reputation wall for a reason. It's a heuristic that's meant to check you understand how the site works and how to conduct yourself in this format. So, if you don't have the rep, you won't gain it by trying to go around the restriction.

Comment: @StoryTeller Completely agree. That's why I am trying to help person by answering via "Add another Answer".